# How can I retrieve just the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration using kubectl -o jsonpath?

Tags: kubectl, jsonpath

I am trying to retrieve the kubernetes last-applied-configuration from a service yaml (under metadata annoations) using kubectl -o jsonpath, but the name of the field is "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration". I believe the parser is getting confused due to the dots in the actual name field, since it uses dots for child object designation.

e.g. (Running on Windows)

```
kubectl -lapp=myapp get service -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{
.metadata.annotations}{\"\n\"}{end}"
```

shows the map of resulting values as expected

```
map[kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:{"kind":"Service","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"myapp","namespace":"mynamespace",
"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"app":"myapp","version":"1.0"}},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http","protocol":"TCP","port":80,"ta
rgetPort":8080}],"selector":{"app":"myapp","version":"1.0"},"type":"NodePort"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}}]
```

In this case, the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration is the only thing in the annotations, but that is not always the case.

The problem comes about when I try to drill down to just the last-applied-configuration.

e.g.

```
kubectl -lapp=myapp get service -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{
.metadata.annotations.kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration}{\"\n\"}{end}"
```

Returns no information.

I have also tried

```
kubectl -lapp=myapp get service -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{
.metadata.annotations['kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration']}{\"\n\"}{end}"
```

and

```
kubectl -lapp=myapp get service -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{['metadata']['annotations']['kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration']}{\"\n\"}{end}"
```

to no avail.

I'm expecting the results to be simply the value of the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration

Answer (score 12):

```
kubectl apply view-last-applied service -lapp=myapp -o json
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to  escape the `.` then it will list out value from the specific annotation name.

```
kubectl -lapp=myapp get service -o jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.annotations.kubectl\.kubernetes\.io/last-applied-configuration}{\"\n\"}{end}"
```